# How do I pass parameters to an Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular service:

```
angular.module('transactionService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Transaction', function($resource){ 
      return $resource('/api/transaction/:transactionId', {}, {
        'query':   {method:'GET',     params:{transactionId : ''},          isArray : true},
        'get':     {method:'GET',     params:{transactionId : '@_id.$oid'}, isArray : false},
        'save':    {method:'POST',    params:{transactionId : ''},          isArray : false},
        'update':  {method:'PUT',     params:{transactionId : '@_id.$oid'}, isArray : false},
      });
});
```

Which I call as:

```
transaction = {
   _id : { $oid : '20495823405984059' }
}
Transaction.update(transaction, function(d) {});
```

But it fetches the URL:

```
/api/transaction/@_id.$oid
```

instead of:

```
/api/transaction/20495823405984059
```

The documentation shows that this is the correct way to pass parameters, but they aren't getting interpolated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
angular.module('transactionService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Transaction', function($resource){ 
      return $resource('/api/transaction/:transactionId', {}, {
        'query':   {method:'GET',     params:{transactionId : ''},          isArray : true},
        'get':     {method:'GET',     params:{transactionId : '@transactionId'}, isArray : false},
        'save':    {method:'POST',    params:{transactionId : ''},          isArray : false},
        'update':  {method:'PUT',     params:{transactionId : '@transactionId'}, isArray : false},
      });
});
```

Call it like this:

```
transaction = {
   transactionId : '20495823405984059' //your problem is the key transactionId is missing
}
Transaction.update(transaction, function(d) {});
```

Comment: It's looking for the key _id.$oid which it does have.

Comment: @nickponline:http://jsfiddle.net/7e3yb/ it seems that your code works (checking console and network)